# Google Tag manager with two UA numbers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was wondering if someone knows if it is possible to use two UA-numbers from Google Analytics within a tag in Google Tag Manager. Or is the only possible by duplicating the tag and use one UA number in both tags.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create two Analytics Tags with different UAIDs if you want to track to different accounts or use a macro that switches between different accounts depending on some condition. However this is would probably better be asked at webmasters.stackexchange.com sind stackoverflow is reserved for code-related questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookup table macro for it. The criteria for lookup table would be, for example, url hostname macro and Google Analytics IDs would be a result.

This way you can use only one tag with different IDs.

Other way is to use hitCallback for GA tag and to fire second GA tag right after first tag.

Comment: Thanks for your response  mrbubu, but the idea is actually a bit more complicated. I would like the tag to be fired twice for two different UA numbers, that is fill two property's instead of one.

Comment: You can also use custom dataLayer events to fire single tag two times for two different IDs